# why I got an output 'b(1) dc dvfunc'?

Tags: c++

My expected output here was " bc bvfunc b(1) dc dvfunc", but I got an output like "b(1) dc dvfunc" why is it so? Could somebody help me out? thanks for your precious time!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

class b {
 public:
  b() {
    cout<<" bc ";
    b::vfunc();
  }
  virtual void vfunc(){ cout<<" bvfunc "; }
  b(int i){ cout<<" b(1) "; }
};

class d : public b {
public:
  d(): b(1) {
    cout<<" dc ";
    d::vfunc();
  }
  void vfunc(){ cout<<" dvfunc"; }
};

main()
{
  d d;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired output you need

```
d(){b(1);      //move b(1) from initializer list and put it in a constructor.  
    cout<<" dc ";
```

FYI `initializer list` is used to `initialize` the member of a class before the constructor call to default value.Constructor can overwrite these values.

Comment: What?! This creates two *different* `b`'s, one that is part of `d` and one temporary that just lives inside the constructor. Hardly useful for anything (except reproducing the output).

Answer (score 1):

The order in which things are done:

d() is called. This calls b(1), and then the rest of the constructor.

So the call order is

```
b(1)
d() -> which is cout fc, and then cout dvfunc
```

b() is never called, so it will not reach bvfunc.
both b() and b(int i) are stand-alone constructors, and only one will be called, not both.